# How to handle a moving object in pygame without having to constantly redraw the background

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a simple game where there's a moveable, in my case, image. It is just controlled by the arrow keys, and this functionality works fine. However I've got the issue of it leaving behind its trail, of which one should solve by adding `screen.fill((0, 0, 0))` so it removes the previous position. However, drawing my background involves reading 900 lines of data and displaying 900 32x32p images, so when I also have to redraw my background it seems python can't handle doing this constantly crashes. Is there another way I can have a moving image while still retaining my background?

Some relevant code:

For drawing the background

```
    while Scene1Read == False:
    read = open("testgraphics.txt", "r")
    xcoords = -32
    ycoords = 0
    squarenum = 0
    for x in read:
        squarenum += 1
        if xcoords < 1024:
            xcoords += 32
        else:
            xcoords = -32
            ycoords += 32
        squarecolorformatting = x[-6:]
        squarecolor = squarecolorformatting[:-1]
        if squarecolor == "METAL":
            img = pygame.image.load("metal.png")
            screen.blit(img, (xcoords,ycoords))
        elif squarecolor == "SANDx":
            img = pygame.image.load("sand.png")
            screen.blit(img, (xcoords,ycoords))
        elif squarecolor == "TRAPD":
            img = pygame.image.load("trapdoor.png")
            screen.blit(img, (xcoords,ycoords))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,colorsdict[squarecolor], [xcoords,ycoords,32,32])
        terminalfont = pygame.font.Font("falloutterminal.ttf", 16)
        testtext1 = terminalfont.render(str(squarenum), False, (255, 0, 255))
        screen.blit(testtext1,(xcoords,ycoords))
    Scene1Read = True
    read.close()
```

For moving the character

```
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        x1_change = -16
        y1_change = 0
    elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        x1_change = 16
        y1_change = 0
    elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        x1_change = 0
        y1_change = -16
    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        x1_change = 0
        y1_change = 16
x1 += x1_change
y1 += y1_change
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your background scroll or have dynamic elements that move around? If not and it's just a static background, one solution that I did for my game was I made the background into one image file so each time it was redrawing the background it only had to deal with one blit function call instead of blitting each tile to redraw the background. There may be other solutions I don't know about, but I would recommend thinking about that option

Comment: Also you do not have to redraw the entire background. If you know what you have moved, you can just blit the section of the background that the moved image used to cover. That will erase just the old image, getting rid of the trail.